# Step by step instruction required to install Canon TS3150 Printer

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I set up a friends old Windows PC with Ubuntu (now on 16.04 LTS) last year and managed to install the necessary drivers for their Brother printer.  This printer recently died and unbeknown to me they purchased a Canon TS3150 'all in one'

I have trawlled the internet for a solution, but am still unable to get the computer to talk with the printer.  I found some driver packages on a Canon site and downloaded this, but to be honest, I don't really know what to do next.  Every step I have tried results in some error or other, and as such, I wondered if anyone could write a tutorial (or idiots guide) to getting things working.

Obviously you may require more info, so please ask away.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Canon/Canon-PIXMA_TS3150 This does not look promising. This https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/18 does though.

Comment: @Bruni nice one but there IS a Ubuntu reporitory; That should be easier to use.

Comment: Steve: https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon has all canon drivers that we can use on Ubuntu. Normally it is best to search for Ubuntu related stuff on Ubuntu related sites (ie. launchpad for drivers). (edit: or use this https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon-trunk ) And yes, I know these are old but they are very restricted to usage so installing the one from an older Ubuntu is not a problem

Comment: found a more updated: https://launchpad.net/~inameiname/+archive/ubuntu/stable

Answer (score 8):

**I would suggest using the drivers that Canon supply for their printer;**

please go here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100910801.html and click to download and SAVE what will be **cnijfilter2-5.50-1-deb.tar.gz** and it should end up in our Downloads folder.Canon released this 8th Dec 2017.

Below will be some commands; each line needs to be copied and then pasted into a terminal; hit the ENTER key after each paste; then move to the next command;

*to paste into the terminal; right-click at the text prompt: the flashing light; you should see a MENU there, and select PASTE from that*

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf cnijfilter2-5.50-1-deb.tar.gz
cd cnijfilter2-5.50-1-deb
```

then the install script; watch as it runs, as it will ask you questions

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

so that should 1) install the drivers and 2) register the printer on lpadmin

(I had understood the michael gruz ppa was no longer supported; support stopped in 2015 or so?)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info.  I have gone through the steps but in Terminal, after sud ./install.sh I get the following info:   Command executed = sudo dpkg -iG ./packages/cnijfilter2_5.50-1_i386.deb
dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process
Command executed = sudo dpkg -P cnijfilter2
dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually, I have now sorted it. I had to close down everything else that was open, leaving just the terminal open, then re-enter the sudo command and my password. We now have a fully functioning printer, so thanks very much :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest to first attempt installing through the generic Ubuntu method: using a repository from launchpad. For Canon there is 1 user that used to maintain this and he has 2 repositories: "regular" and "daily updates". 1 issue: it has been 200+ weeks since the last update on "daily updates".

Nevertheless still the best 1st attempt. So add this repository to your system.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inameiname/stable
sudo apt-get update
```

and then install these packages:

```
sudo apt install cndrvcups
sudo apt install cnijfilter
sudo apt install scangearmp
```

If this works it should install support for your printer and your scanner.

====

- edit: changed the repo to a newer one
- if it does not work please leave a comment!

Comment: I am not at the actual computer now but I think I used the repository command line as above.  When I hit 'enter' at the end of /stable, a lot of lines of script pulled in, so I then wrote the 'update' command line and hit 'enter' but could get anything to work.  I assume I am using the command line correctly?  I will try from scratch again tomorrow but this time note the actual errors.  Thanks for the suggestions so far

Comment: Doesn't work. E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/inameiname/stable/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.

Answer (score 0):

Great help in getting TS3150 working under Ubuntu 14. Needed to copy the sudo command to get it to work (did not seem to work when typed in).

Shame needed to run windows install (using USB) to get the printer to switch on WIFI.

Comment: By the way what about the scanner portion?  Windows has an application called IJ Scan Utility (and presumably associated driver)