# 18.04: driver installation error, Canon ts3150

Tags: printing, canon

I am trying to install the drivers for canon ts3150 on  Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, Bionic. It's a wi fi printer and it sucessfully prints from my phone. I've tried

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inameiname/stable
```

from  [Step by step instruction required to install Canon TS3150 Printer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030598/step-by-step-instruction-required-to-install-canon-ts3150-printer) and got this error:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.
GPG error: https://debian.neo4j.org/repo stable/ Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 26C95CF201182252 Neo Technology Admins <admins@neotechnology.com>
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz` also gives a very long error.

`sudo apt install libxml2 libglade2-0 libpng12-0 libtiff5`   gives the error:

```
Package libpng12-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libpng12-0' has no installation candidate
```

Also, downloading the drivers from https://asia.canon/en/support/0100910801 and trying `sudo install.sh` didn't work:

```
install.sh: command not found
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'xxx' doesn't support architecture 'i386'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741410/skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-main-binary-i386-packages-as-repository-x)